# How can i tell if geth is done running?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, command-line, solo-mining

Well i am new trying to mine and i did the "C:>geth --rpc" and its still going how will i know when its done? i did all the steps leading to this but my pc just keeps running the

```
INFO [05-18|23:32:54] Imported new block receipts              count=36   elapsed=56.012ms   number=3277546 hash=01c020…980ee0 ignored=0
INFO [05-18|23:32:56] Imported new state entries               count=41   elapsed=1.918s     processed=8876747 pending=36176
```

Just keeps going on, How to tell if geth is done syncing?

Comment: How long does it usually take ?

Answer (score 26):

The way I check is:

- Find out what the last block is. https://etherchain.org
- Start geth with console (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)
- When geth is running enter the command eth.syncing

eth.syncing will show you your block sync info. You are looking for currentBlock.

Example:

```
./geth console
> eth.syncing
```

Output:

```
{ currentBlock: 2629645, highestBlock: 4895563, knownStates: 7631432, pulledStates: 7625973, startingBlock: 12096 }
```

or

```
false
```

If you see output false, you have caught up with the chain.

Also you will start seeing geth outputting chain segment when done with syncing.

```
Imported new chain segment
```

Comment: I hope this is the best answer. If so please can you accept it ;)

Comment: Run `geth attach` if you want to attach to the already running geth process.

Answer (score 5):

Compare the value in the log file in the field named number with the value of the last block here https://etherscan.io
If it equals or near to equal it means that your chain synchronized.

Comment: im pretty far behind do i close it or let it run and download the ether wallet?

Comment: It takes quite a while to sync, a couple days for some people. You just have to wait

Comment: Mine is not outputing the "number" field any more, my lines look like this :


INFO [07-05|17:13:20] Imported new state entries               count=36  flushed=42  elapsed=577.373µs processed=444595 pending=24261 retry=4   duplicate=1040 unexpected=2419

Answer (score 2):

You can use different methods.

(1) Find out what the latest block is from someone who is up to date (or a online block-explorer like etherscan.io / etherchain.org), compare that to where your chain is.

(2) Once you start importing blocks 1 by 1 every ~15sec, instead of in chunks of 20-50, you are probably up to date.

Comment: Oh, so no way to know for sure?